# Django forms.ModelForm POST change object before update

Tags: python, django, database, post, modelform

Via a standard HTML POST form I can successfully update an existing record with the below code but the situation is that I need to change one data field before I save the form data to the database. On the Django website, they say make a new form instance and change the field but for whatever reason the field data does not change in the save() action.

```
class ProvisioningDetails(View):
def post(self, request, provisioning_ptr_id, terminal_id, site_id):
    form = ProvisioningForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
     a = Provisioning.objects.get(provisioning_ptr_id=provisioning_ptr_id)
    
     f = ProvisioningForm(request.POST, instance=a)
     f.str1 = "some new data"
     f.save()

     return redirect(
        "provisionings_show_view", site_id, terminal_id, provisioning_ptr_id
    )

class ProvisioningForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Provisioning
    fields = [
        "id",
        "fixedip",
        "str1",
        "str2",
        "str3",
        "ip",
    ]


def clean(self,):
    cleaned_data = super(ProvisioningForm, self).clean()
```

I also tried this which does change the data in the form but not in the database:

```
    class ProvisioningDetails(View):
def post(self, request, provisioning_ptr_id, terminal_id, site_id):
    form = ProvisioningForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
     a = Provisioning.objects.get(provisioning_ptr_id=provisioning_ptr_id)
    
     new = ProvisioningForm(request.POST)
     new.str1 = "some new data" 
     f = ProvisioningForm(new, instance=a)
     f.save()

     return redirect(
        "provisionings_show_view", site_id, terminal_id, provisioning_ptr_id
    )
```

Anyone know how I can get the str1 = "some new data" save in the database

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was simple:

```
post = request.POST.copy()
post.update({"str1": "some new text"})

a = Provisioning.objects.get(provisioning_ptr_id=provisioning_ptr_id)

f = ProvisioningForm(post, instance=a)
f.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `a.str1 = "new data"` and then do `a.save()` if you want to change one field in the database with the new data.

Else if you want to change the request payload data and then save you can use `Provisioning.objects.create('your fields here')` and .save()

Either way I think you're better off using a serializer:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: The issue with this is after setting a.str1 = "new data" , yes at that pointit  updates the object but then it will be overwritten by  f = ProvisioningForm(request.POST, instance=a) and the fields in request (Post) do overwrite the  newly set a.str1 = "new data"

Comment: I'm not still very clear about what you want to do:
Save the form first and then get the object and edit:
f=...

....

 a = Provisioning.objects.get(provisioning_ptr_id=provisioning_ptr_id)
a.str1 = " " 
 a.save()

Comment: The situation is dat I receive in the request.POST the field str1 with an array which I cannot store in the database. So when I update the database first I get an database error because the array is not permitted. what I want to do is request.Post and change the field in to an integer.. so I have tried your suggestion vut I am not ables to change the field gorm the request.POST >>> chaneg the field and save.